# JavaScript calculator with two inputs and four operations

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

i build a calc & want to a review that what i did wrong & what is right method to do.

```html
    <html>
  <script>
    
    var inputIdFirst = "valueOfX",inputIdSecond = "valueOfY",outputId = "resultHere";
    var getInputs = function(id) {
      return parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
    }
    var showOutput = function(outputValue, outputIdAsArg) {
      //if no argument is given then by default "outputId" taken
      document.getElementById(outputId).innerHTML = outputValue;
    }
    var manuplateAs = function(operationName, valueOfX, valueOfY) {
      if(operationName == 'add')
        return valueOfX + valueOfY;
      else if(operationName == 'sub')
        return valueOfX - valueOfY;
      else if(operationName == 'mul')
        return valueOfX * valueOfY;
      else if(operationName == 'div')
        return valueOfX / valueOfY;
      //can add as many as you wish 
    } 
    var operation = function(operationName){
      x = getInputs(inputIdFirst);
      y = getInputs(inputIdSecond);
      output = manuplateAs(operationName, x, y);
      showOutput(output);
      console.log(x + " " + operationName + " " + y + " = " + output)
      //see console to understand this more
      console.log(this)
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
      Enter first number
      <input type="number" id="valueOfX">
      Enter second number
      <input type="number" id="valueOfY">
      <button onclick="operation('add')"> Add </button>
      <button onclick="operation('sub')"> Sub</button>
      <button onclick="operation('mul')"> Mult</button>
      <button onclick="operation('div')"> Divi</button>
      <h1 id="resultHere"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the ball rolling, a few things that come to mind:

## JavaScript

### Storing DOM-elements

In `getInputs` and `showOuput` you use `document.getElementById` to get the same DOM elements over and over again. You can simply store or "*cache*" them in variable an re-use them anytime you want:

```
var inputX = document.getElementById('x'),
    inputY = document.getElementById('y'),
    output = document.getElementById('output');
```

`showOutput` which seems to have an unused value in its signature, would now look like:

```
var showOutput = function(value) {
    output.innerHTML = value;
}
```

### Filter input

`getInputs` already uses `parseInt` to filter the user's input. This will still result in `NaN` for all inputs that can't be parsed to integer, like `"hey"`.

You should test for this scenario and give the user a hint that something failed:

```
var operation = function(operationName) {
    var x = getInputs(inputX),
        y = getInputs(inputY);

    if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)) {
        // show an error message or give the inputs a red border etc.
        return;
    }

    // […]
};
```

By the way, your calculator doesn't make it clear, that it can only process integer values, which might lead to confusing results with inputs like this:

> 1.5 + 2.5 = 3

Improve the UX and leave the visitor a note.

### `manuplateAs`

I think you meant to call the function `manipulate`. But why don't you simply call it `calculate`?

You can also use a `switch`-statement and shorter variable names to increase readability:

```
var calculate = function(operation, x, y) {
    switch(operation) {
        case 'add': return x + y;
        case 'sub': return x - y;
        case 'mul': return x * y;
        case 'div': return x / y;
    };
}
```

Again your calculator doesn't handle edge cases. For example it will show `Infinity` for division by `0` or `NaN` if numbers get to big.

You could test the result for `NaN` or `Infinity` and show a proper message to the user:

```
var result = calculate('div', x, y);

if (!isFinite(result)) {
    // show an error message
    return;
}
```

---

#### HTML

### `<head>`

Event though it's a very simply example, add these two things in your header:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple Calculator</title>
```

It makes sure that:

- The correct character set is chosen.
- The user can find the tab with the calculator more easily.

### Form

You're using form elements that are not descendants of a `form` element, nor do you link them to a form using the `form`-attribute. That is invalid HTML. Simply wrap everything into a form:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id="x">
    <input type="number" id="y">
</form>
```

A `button` is by default a *submit* button. You can change this by setting the `type`-attribute:

```
<button type="button" onclick="operation('add')">Add</button>
```

To further improve UX create labels to couple your text with a corresponding input. This also makes sure, that the input is focused as soon as a user clicks the label's text:

```
<label>
    First number
    <input type="number" id="x">
</label>
```

Or alternatively:

```
<label for="x">First number</label>
<input type="number" id="x">
```

---

Personally I wouldn't use a `h1`-element to output the result. Maybe a disabled input field works here, too.

Comment: thank you very much bro, i'll always remember your given advice